# Passing values (integer) between forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

My problem is that I have two forms, Form1 and Form2 ...on Form1 there is a `TextBox` called txtTotal (this contains the calculation of Ticket Prices, thus it's a numeric value) and on Form2 there is a `TextBox` called txtTotal2.  All I want to do is get the same number that appears in txtTotal on Form1 to appear in txtTotal2 on Form2

However whenever I try some of the help tips online such as using a declaring txtTotal as global or friend it dosn't work, and any other code iv tried attempts pass the textbox value as String which brings an error.

Any help wld be much appreciated :)

Comment: Show us what you've tried and what's wrong with it, and we'll show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Form2 should either have public properties for the integer values that need to be passed, or take those values in it's constructor, then form1, when creating form2, will set those values, and then show the form.

Answer (score 0):

[image: designer snapshot]

form1 code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public x As String = "msg from form2"
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
        TextBox2.Text = Form2.x
    End Sub
End Class
```

form2 code:

```
Public Class Form2
    Public x As String = "msg from form1"
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
        TextBox2.Text = Form1.x
    End Sub

End Class
```